# Visual Studio Installation Failing

Tags: visual-studio

Previously I have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate version in my system. Its is working fine.

Later I am trying to install 2013 also but it is not installing properly and giving error message like attached image.After that VS2012 also is not working properly. Then I tried to Install Vs2012 also again. But this installation process also giving same error. I can not able to upload image due to reputation.

This is the exact error:

"Visual Studio Core Fetures Fatal error during installing.
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Core Libraries Package failed.
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Microsoft Foundation Class Library Package failes."

Please help me to install visual studio 2012 & 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Visual Studio requires many components to be installed, and if they are not, VS will install them. However, when you uninstall VS, it will not remove these components automatically because it does not record which component is installed by it and which exists before VS is installed. Other applications might need these components to work.

When you uninstall VS2012, you really **only** remove VS itself. Then you try to install VS2013 and meet an error, and that may be the problem. To make things worse, you did not **clean** uninstall VS2013 either, which caused the later errors when you try to reinstall VS2012.

You may as well try to [clean uninstall VS 2012](https://helloacm.com/clean-uninstall-of-visual-studio-2010-and-2012-and-install-free-visual-studio-2013-community-version/) and the same goes for VS 2013, just some Google work.

I hope this will help you a little.